Issues with ESM and CJS module resolution in my TypeScript package
I have developed a JavaScript scoped package named @rushipatange/calculate-it using TypeScript and Rollup, and I want to support both CommonJS (CJS) and ECModule (ESM) formats. I've transpiled my code to both formats and set up my package.json accordingly, but I'm encountering an issue when trying to use the package in an ESM context with .js extensions and will work with .mjs extensions . You can find the code here.
My Setup:

Languages/Technologies: TypeScript, Rollup
Transpiler: Rollup for bundling
Target Formats: CJS and ESM

package.json configuration:
{
  "name": "@rushipatange/calculate-it",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.mjs", // will not work with .js extensions
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/index.mjs", // will not work with .js extensions
      "require": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/esm/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && rollup -c rollup.config.mjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "calci",
    "calculator"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^4.22.2",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.36.0",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  }
}

Rollup Configuration:
Here's a simplified version of my Rollup config:
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import { defineConfig } from "rollup";

// Common Rollup plugins
const commonPlugins = [commonjs(), resolve(), typescript()];

// ESM Configuration
const esmConfig = defineConfig({
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    dir: "dist/esm",
    format: "es",
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true,
    preserveModulesRoot: "src",
    entryFileNames: "[name].mjs", // will not work with .js
  },
  plugins: [...commonPlugins],
});

// CommonJS Configuration
const cjsConfig = defineConfig({
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    dir: "dist/cjs",
    format: "cjs",
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true,
    preserveModulesRoot: "src",
    entryFileNames: "[name].js",
  },
  plugins: [...commonPlugins],
});

export default [esmConfig, cjsConfig];

Issue:
When I try to import the package in an ESM context (e.g., in a .mjs file), it still redirects me to the CJS version. For example:
import { add } from '@rushipatange/calculate-it'; // This imports the CJS version

What I've Tried:

Ensured that package.json correctly specifies both main and module.
Ensured that package.json correctly specifies exports field
Verified that the output files are being generated correctly.
Tried with .mjs extenstion by changing esmConfig entryFileNames field (it works)

Questions:

What could be causing the ESM import to resolve to the CJS version?
Are there any additional settings or configurations I should be aware of to ensure proper ESM support?
Why it works with .mjs file extensions and not with .js extensions ?
How can I make it workable for both ESM and CJS without .mjs extenstion ?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
